# event hub triggered azure functions app geo-disaster recovery

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub, geo-replication

This is our application architecture and I am trying to figure out Geo-disaster recovery for the whole application. Both the functions in the architecture are part of **same** function-app. Eventhub Geo-disaster can be achieved by setting up secondary name space [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-geo-dr). This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-geo-disaster-recovery#activepassive-for-non-https-functions) talk about Geo-disaster recovery for Active/passive for non-HTTPS functions, this aligns with subscriber in our application

My question is how to architect the Geo-disaster recovery of the **publisher** which is a **timer triggered function**.

```
PUBLISHER(AZURE-FUNCTION)--------------->EVENTHUB-------------> SUBSCRIBER(AZURE-FUNCTION)
```

[image]

Comment: what exactly is your question? how to deploy your timer triggered Function is two regions and how to activate it?

Comment: Yes, how to architect  Geo-disaster recovery for just timer functions and how to activate it?